How to make the DatagridView columns when editing the value appear not in currency format in vb.net
I'm trying to make the DataGridView columns when editing the value appear not in currency format in vb.net.
I also attach a GIF file in this post.
Or maybe the code I'm using is wrong
or is there another way I need to do?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Below Code in form1
Public Class Form1
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)

    End Sub
    Private Sub CalculateTotal()
        Dim tot As Double = 0
        For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim quantity As Double = 0
            Dim price As Double = 0
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("Qty").Value) Then
                Double.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("Qty").Value, String), quantity)
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("PRICE").Value) Then
                Double.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("PRICE").Value, String), price)
            End If

            tot += (quantity * price)
        Next item
        lblTotal.Text = tot.ToString("N")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Products)}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        DataGridView1.Columns("TOTAL").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        DataGridView1.Columns("TOTAL").DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        updateDataSource()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
    sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim PRICE As Double = Nothing, QTY As Double = Nothing, TOTAL As Double = Nothing
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not Double.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value.ToString(), QTY) Then
                QTY = 0
            End If
        Else
            QTY = 0
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value = QTY
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("PRICE").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not Double.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("PRICE").Value.ToString(), PRICE) Then
                PRICE = 0
            End If
        Else
            PRICE = 0
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("PRICE").Value = PRICE
        TOTAL = (QTY * PRICE)
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("TOTAL").Value = TOTAL
        CalculateTotal()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Products
    Public Property PRODUCTNAME() As String
    Public Property QTY() As Double
    Public Property PRICE() As Double
    Public Property TOTAL() As Double
End Class

The result of the above code in a gif file


@jmcilhinney , What do you think "c2" means as a format? I mean this is DefaultCellStyle.Format in datagridview. Thanks for your respond .I've solved the solution and I answered in this post

Ah, I owe you an apology. I misread your question and thought you were asking for something other than what you are. Again, my apologies.

I down-voted your question but, now that I realise my mistake, see that I shouldn't have. I made an insignificant edit to your question so that I could retract that vote.

@jmcilhinney ,Ah, I owe you an apology. I misread your question and thought you were asking for something other than what you are. Again, my apologies. I've apologized to you

@jmcilhinney , If indeed the answer I posted is not correct, then please you can give me the correct answer and solution

as per this link!
The solution is to add a DefaultCellStyle.Format in event datagridvidew CellBeginEdit
    Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Products)}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        DataGridView1.Columns("TOTAL").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        DataGridView1.Columns("TOTAL").DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        updateDataSource()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
    sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso
        dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE") Then
            Dim price1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("PRICE").Value)
            DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
            DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("c2")
    End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso
        dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("PRICE") Then
            dgv.Columns("PRICE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = ""
        End If
    End Sub





Now that I have read your question properly and understand what you actually want, I can say that this is not the solution. You should not be changing the format for the whole column or even the cell being edited. When you start editing a cell, the grid creates an editing control (or reuses the last one if it's the correct type) so the only place you have to worry about the formatting is in that control. I will provide an answer with the "correct" solution.

@jmcilhinney , I will provide an answer with the "correct" solution Thank you and ok if indeed you give the correct answer then I will follow from your answer
